Is persistent history tracking in CoreData supported with legacy stack and Objective C?
Is it possible to implement Persistent History Tracking in an application/framework written in Objective C where Core Data stack has been setup manually in legacy manner? Or does persistent history tracking work only when persistent store was initialised by NSPersistentContainer available from iOS 10 onwards?

NSPersistentContainer and NSPersistentHistory... are unrelated.

NSPersistentContainer is a convenience but is not necessary. If you're not using it, you also don't have NSPersistentStoreDescription, so you'll set any custom options on your persistent store coordinator instead. If you check out the docs for NSPersistentStoreCoordinator you'll see that persistent history tracking is one of the available options.
Persistent history tracking was added in iOS 11, so it won't work on earlier versions of iOS regardless of how you set up Core Data.

Thanks Tom for the answer. Another quick question and a clarification - I have an app and an app extension. I have a requirement for the extension to access and write data into app's Core Data backend. I assume I can do this using persistent history tracking. And I guess I also need to enable app groups on both the app and the extension and copy the core data db to shared UserDefaults? Or can the persistent history tracking work without app group in this case? Thanks again

App groups and persistent history tracking are not related. You need an app group to share any kind of data between an app and an extension, whether or not you use persistent history or even whether or not you use Core Data. Also, Core Data and user defaults are separate things that don't connect. You would put the Core Data store in a shared directory, not user defaults. There are numerous past questions here on SO about setting up shared data directories.
